# Find non-ASCII codepoints in a file

Tags: regex, linux, encoding, grep

I am currently using this regex to find the non-ASCII code points in a file, no matter what encoding:

```
$ cat test.txt | hd | grep -P " [8-9a-f][\da-f]"
```

**Is there a better, more concise, or less hacky method?** I usually use `grep -P "[^\x00-\x7f]"` to find the offensive **characters** but here I am looking for the offensive **code points**.

Note that the current hacky method does have the nice side effect of showing the surrounding ASCII characters, which is very nice for context.

Comment: extra process with `cat`. doesn't `hd < test.txt | grep -P ...` work? My RedHat Linux doesn't have `hd`. Ah, found it on my Redhat Linux as `hexdump`. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter: Thanks, that cleans it up a bit.

Comment: And, of course the Unix toolbox approach is to use small tools that do 1 thing well, and rely on pipelines to connect together a solution (`tar`, are you listening?). There may be a specific tool for what you're attempting, but I think this solution is (excepting the `cat`) meets the spirit of Unix/Linux programming. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Using hd, this should be faster:

```
hd test.txt |grep -w '[89a-f][0-9a-f]'
```

(`grep -P` invokes libpcre and is slower. `grep -w` searches just "words" and will default to standard posix regex, which is nearly as fast as a `-F` plain text query.  Removing the `cat` from the pipe also saves (trivial) effort.)

If you didn't want the context, you could give grep the `-o` flag.  If you want the context called out more clearly, consider `--color` (or even `--color=always` if you're piping the output somewhere and don't mind the coloring control characters).  You may also find grep's `-n` flag useful, which will give you line numbers.

I *think* you can use grep's `-a` flag to achieve what you're looking for in a single command (this forces everything to be read as text rather than the useless "Binary file test.txt matches" output), though you may not like what the output does to your terminal.  Maybe pipe it into a file and then view that file with `vim` (which, unlike `less`, won't render control characters):

```
grep -aP '[^\x00-\x7f]' test.txt > found-highchars
view found-highchars
```

This may or may not be faster than piping through `hd` and `grep`.